# Python - Queue - Why does my tuple get chopped up?

Tags: python, string, multithreading, queue, tuples

Why is it that when I put a tuple into a queue like this:

```
myqueue.put(('Thread Started'))
```

And I call .get() like this:

```
item = myqueue.get()
print item
```

It prints this:

```
('T', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'd', ' ', 'S', 't', 'a', 'r', 't', 'e', 'd')
```

What is the reason for this behavior? How can I get my original tuple back?

Comment: That's not a tuple, it's a string in parentheses.  If you want it to be a tuple, you need a comma: `('Thread Started',)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a tuple, that's a string in a pair of parentheses. This is a tuple:

```
myqueue.put(('Thread Started', ))
```

Answer (score 6):

A tuple is constructed with a comma:

```
>>> (1,)
(1,)
```

this, however, is just '1':

```
>>> (1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

The code as written shouldn't produce the output if `myqueue` is `Queue.Queue` instance.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
myqueue.put('Thread Started')
item = myqueue.get()
print item
```

And it should produce just: `Thread Started`.

A tuple is created with a comma:

```
t = 1,
# -> (1,)
t = 'a', 'b', 'c'
# -> ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Or you could call the constructor explicitly:

```
t = tuple("abc")
# -> ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

The exception is an empty tuple that is created with `()`:

```
t = ()
# -> ()
t = tuple()
# -> ()
```